# Who gets to write book reviews for academic journals?

Tags: publications, books, review-articles

Some journals publish reviews of newly published books in their field. It's not clear how authors for these reviews are typically chosen. Can you apply for writing a review? Or should you do just like for a regular paper: buy the book, read it, write your review and submit it? How is this typically handled? Is it reserved to the editors to initiate such reviews?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am sure this varies but is most likely one of the following (in some kind of falling order):

> - you are a well-known and respected researcher/educator in the field
> - you have recently written material that are key to the book (perhaps referenced in it)
> - you are known not to know the word "No" (makes the editors work easier)
> - you are friends with the editor (makes his/her life easy)

I doubt many editors will necessarily take you up on an offer (depending which category you may fall into) but I am sure some might be fine with it. It never hurts to contact an editor and express interest. You should then provide a background for why you should be considered for such a task.